# Extract sub-strings from string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following String:

```
mac1: 00:11:22:33:44:55
mac2: 66:77:88:99:00:11
model: PI-504
first_name: any_name
device_type: baseboard
serial_number: 668778542298745210
```

And I want to extract all values into an array. How to do it with Java?

```
public String[] getvaluesIntoStringArray(String str) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you search the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html)? or the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: How should the `String[]` look like? Please provide sample output. Something like `{"mac1", "00:11:22:33:44:55", ...}` or `{"mac1", "mac2", ...}` or `{"00:11:22:33:44:55", "66:77:88:99:00:11", ...}` or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split new lines then I think this should do it

```
public String[] getvaluesIntoStringArray(String str) {
    return str.split("\\r?\\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex):

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*?:(.*)");

public static String[] getvaluesIntoStringArray(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(str);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find())
        values.add(matcher.group(1).trim());
    return values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=:\s)(.+$)`
if your regex engine does not suppirt lookbehind use this regex `(:\s)(.+$)` matches will be in group 2

p.s.: use regex with regexoption `MultyLine`

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "mac1: 00:11:22:33:44:55
mac2: 66:77:88:99:00:11
model: PI-504
first_name: any_name
device_type: baseboard
serial_number: 668778542298745210";

String[] tempArr = str.split("\n");
```

this tempArr should contain the values as mac1: 00:11:22:33:44:55 , mac2: 66:77:88:99:00:11,model: PI-504,first_name: any_name,device_type: baseboard,serial_number: 668778542298745210

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
String[] result = str.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        String str = "mac1: 00:11:22:33:44:55\n" +
                     "mac2: 66:77:88:99:00:11\n" +
                     "model: PI-504\n" +
                     "first_name: any_name\n" +
                     "device_type: baseboard\n" +
                     "serial_number: 668778542298745210";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*?:(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        boolean find = matcher.find();
        while(find) {
            result.add(matcher.group(1));
            find = matcher.find();
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
```